# Get and save all items from mutilselect using rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

[image]

I have these two mutiselects, I want to save all the items (India, Japan, Brazil, USA) of Included list to database without selecting. If I select mutiple it will work but I want to save whatever there in included list.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can keep all bydefault selected and when you click on `Save Included` it will save all

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when user unselect it, it will be there in list but will not save. I want to save whatever there in list.

Comment: Add value as selected to the item when user push item to inlcuded, so whatever in Included is all selected then save on "save" action

Comment: Suppose your item is 'Australia' and you move it then it is added to included box whose id is `included` at last position then you can say `$(function() {
  $('#included option:last').prop('selected', true);
});`

Comment: Yes but if user click on Australia in list it will be unselected.

Comment: Correct last try this function will give you all the values in included, `function sendData() {
    var c = document.getElementById("included");
    var val = "values: ";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        val = val + "\n" + c.options[i].text;
    }
    return val;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make "save Included" as simple button not submit button. Then using jquery you can select all items of this listbox on click event of "Save Included" button and submit the form too through same click event in jquery after selecting all options of listbox.
You can use the following jQuery code:

```
 $('#save_included_button').click(function () {
         $('#included_carriers option').prop('selected', true);
        $('#included_carriers_form').submit();
    });
```

Change the ids in code according to your html.

Thanks.